# Set a security rule firebase based on a users oauth email

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Is there a way to securely get the email that they OAuthed in with in a security rule.

Ideally i wanted to create a rule like:

```
{
    ".read": "auth.google.email.matches(/@example.com$/)"
    ".write": "auth.google.email.matches(/@example.com$/)"
}
```

So that the entire application, or section of an application is secured to an email address suffix. This is a much easier of way to manage my application because the users will be given access based on the company email they have, all or nothing.

Alternatively is theres a way to save the users email address to the database which they then cant write to i believe i could achieve a similar process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auth. properties of OAuth providers are not available in security rules. Per the [documentation on the auth variable](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-variable):

> The predefined `auth` variable is null before authentication takes place. Once a user is authenticated by Firebase Login's auth method, it will contain the following attributes:
>
> **provider**  The authentication method used ("password", "anonymous", "facebook", "github", "google", or "twitter").
>
> **uid**   A unique user id, guaranteed to be unique across all providers.

So you cannot secure the data based on the email address, unless you involve a server to provide the email domain in a secure way.

Once you involve a server, you can either:

- verify the email address and store the verified email address in the database. Then you can access it in your security rules with something like `root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('emailDomain').val()`
- [mint your own tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html) that include the email domain, so that it becomes available in the the `auth` variable in your security rules with something like `auth.emailDomain`.